# How to get a value from a promise to global scope in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on user authentication using web tokens in react. I am using `fetch()` to make a `POST` request to my backend using CORS. Trying to use `setToken()` hook inside the `.then()` gives an error. I tried storing the token to another variable, and using `setToken()` outside the promise, but to no avail. Here's the code:

```
const [ token, setToken ] = useState('')

// Configuration for POST fetch method
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/users/login'
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify(userData)
}

let tempToken = ''
fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    tempToken = data.token
    // console.log(tempToken)  // DEBUG
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e))

setToken(tempToken)
// console.log(token) // This logs default value of token, which is ''
```

This is all inside a function. What is going wrong here? Also is there another way to do this, much appreciated. Thanks.

**What is my problem: Cannot extract `token` from promise.**

P.S: Also, on a completely different note, I tried using async await but it gave a response (shown below), where I couldn't even find the body of the json. Hence using `.then()`

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/users/login", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:8080/users/login"
__proto__: Response
```

Comment: What error did `setToken(data.token)` *inside* the promise callback give?

Comment: `fetch()` is **asynchronous**. You can't eat a pizza before it gets delivered. Similarly you can't call `setToken()` before you receive the token

Comment: @jonrsharpe its says, `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`. Even though its a warning and not an error, it still prints `null`

Comment: That suggests that the promise resolves *after* the component has been unmounted again.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry but could you elaborate more about mounting please?

Comment: See e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fetch` returns a `promise`, you need wait to get the token and then use `setToken`. Moreover you're calling fetch directly and updating the state even before rendering, that might leads to `warnings/side effects`. You can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#effect-hook) hook to call api and update the state

```
useEffect(() => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:8080/users/login'
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(userData)
  }
  fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    setToken(data.token)
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
}, [])
```

Comment: I mentioned in my post, doing this causes a `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`

Comment: Yes, because you're updating the state `setToken(tempToken)` without even component renders, That's why your getting that `warning`, try to use hook like above, it will work

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice the `useEffect()`. That worked, but I had to set the second parameter to `[ email, password ]`. But I assume, this is not good design?, since every time email and password fields are updated, `fetch()` runs again

Comment: That's right, those are dependencies, `useEffect` will run when `dependencies` changes.

Comment: Thanks Naren. Last query, is there a better way to do this, if not, will if affect my server due to a lot of `fetches`?

Comment: Can check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-signup-verification-boilerplate?file=account%2FLogin.jsx), this one has better way of handling the login functionality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227455/discussion-between-atharvakamble-and-naren).